# Use an array of readonly property keys as TypeScript union

Tags: typescript

I want to declare arrays at the root of the module that are an array of keys that correspond to a model, but can be used in various parts of the app as unions.

```
const editableFields: (keyof Car)[] = ["name", "description"] as const
```

This generates the error:

```
The type 'readonly ["name", "description"]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type '(keyof Car)[]'.ts(4104)
```

I want to be able to create an union from this array, like `"name" | "description"` so that I can use it in various parts of the app, as well as somehow pass it to `lodash` `pick` and `omit` functions:

```
lodash.pick(carInstance, ...editableFields)
```

If I remove the `(keyof Car)[]` it all starts working:

```
const editableFields: readonly ["name", "description"]
```

But then I lose the type safety!

Would love to hear if anyone has set this up successfully. Thanks!

Comment: Or [this one](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJysg3gKGckOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG49kATCChGgBzGAHsRyVGiAY4AvjhxgAnpxQBRZsDBwARgBsIAaQjSKyALzIARIRLHkAHxOt2XHv2P1kAehfJemeQA9qiMAA8ANa6vDBoGAA0JmYQFtbGthzA3HwgxgB8OAj8VMgQSioaZMiKymqaOnoA2gC6hsjVpsRx0YlsyamOtYzZuWDICBjk6JhGuPix5ADkMLy805FMSfZpM6oYi+KSc5gAFJoDIdIe4QXlxQCU2Ew5IBS8mgB06ry0e0NQ1ce1l4wSQA), I'm not sure what the disconnect is here (sorry @jcalz, was working on mine didn't look at yours)

Comment: @jcalz THIS WORKS!!! `const editableFields2 = ["name", "description"] satisfies (keyof Car)[];` WOW! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), any [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals) will get a [`readonly` tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types), which is [a "*read-only*" array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type), but you were trying to assign that to a *mutable* or *read-write* array type, and the compiler doesn't see those as compatible.

One way to fix this is to just [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the variable as `readonly (keyof Car)[]` instead of `(keyof Car)[]` so that the `readonly` conflict goes away:

```
const editableFields1: readonly (keyof Car)[] = ["name", "description"] as const
// const editableFields1: readonly (keyof Car)[]
```

---

Another approach is to use the new [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) instead of a `const` assertion to tell the compiler that you want to be sure that the type of `editableFields2` is assignable to `(keyof Car)[]`.  This gives the compiler a *context* in which to interpret `["name", "description"]`, so that it doesn't get widened to `string[]`:

```
const editableFields2 = ["name", "description"] satisfies (keyof Car)[];
// const editableFields2: ("name" | "description")[]
```

If you made a mistake with one of your fields, then the compiler would output a warning (which is presumably what you mean by losing type safety when you don't annotate).

---

Finally, you could combine these approaches and use a `const` assertion with the right `readonly` type, but still use the `satisfies` operator so that the compiler checks the type without widening it:

```
const editableFields3 = ["name", "description"] as const satisfies readonly (keyof Car)[];
// const editableFields3: readonly ["name", "description"]
```

Here the type of `editableFields3` is as specific as possible; the compiler knows that the first element is `"name"` and the type is `"description"`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJysg3gWAFDKHIhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmA3PkcgCYTUL0AOYwAPYgqteiGb4AvvgTDayCO2Bg4AIwA2EAGLAIG9tQCMVKBDjthGgJ7IAFAGsI1wTDQYAlAG0AusgC8yF4ARCTkwQA0yMGc3HwCwsF+cNTIciC0+AD0WWnyYIrKqpo6egbGpuaWIDb2Ti5u6FDePviy+YUq6lq6+oYATAFBoWQQkdGxPMD8QiBJNHAC1DB6qY7Oru7Nvix4OXkZBUpdJb3l-VR2I+HIAD4TXFMziS1teOkKx8U9ZYYAzEMQmExlEYo94rN5ikDgpqItgMtVsgzBYrLZ1g0ti1dvsPkcit1Sn1qH9KqiarYgaNxmC4tMEnNWnggA)